# Calculating EMI according to selection of select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I have a form in Drupal where I am fetching three value on one select change, two text fields & that select field itself. I am subtracting value which is suppose to be loaned amount and have to calculate EMI based on selection, for which I got one formula but it's not working. Here is the code which I am using...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var actualAmount = 100000;
    var downPayment = 20000;
    var emi_total_amount = actualAmount - downPayment;
    var selected_emi_type = $("#edit-field-payment-emi-und option:selected").text();
    var emi_amount;

    var rate_24 = 15/(12*100);
    var rate_30 = 15/(12*100);
    var rate_36 = 15.5/(12*100);
    var rate_42 = 15.5/(12*100);
    var rate_48 = 16/(12*100);
    switch (selected_emi_type){
        case '6 EMI':
            emi_amount = parseInt(emi_total_amount/6);
            break;
        case '12 EMI':
            emi_amount = parseInt(emi_total_amount/12);
            break;
        case '24 EMI':
            emi_amount = emi_total_amount x rate_24 x (1 + rate_24)24 / ((1+rate_24)24 -1);
            break;
        case '30 EMI':
            emi_amount = emi_total_amount x rate_30 x (1 + rate_30)30 / ((1+rate_30)30 -1);
            break;
        case '36 EMI':
            emi_amount = emi_total_amount x rate_36 x (1 + rate_36)36 / ((1+rate_36)36 -1);
            break;
        case '42 EMI':
            emi_amount = emi_total_amount x rate_42 x (1 + rate_42)42 / ((1+rate_42)42 -1);
            break;
        case '48 EMI':
            emi_amount = emi_total_amount x rate_48 x (1 + rate_48)48 / ((1+rate_48)48 -1);
            break;                          
    }
    alert(emi_amount);
)};
```

I am giving the example value for now. My switch and all other things are working fine and first two switch case too as there is no formula implement. I know there can be problem with this formula but I need solution of it...

Answer (score 0):

Your operators are not valid javascript.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp